# Jest with TS and ES2022 & NodeNext Fails

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

This is a demo code below used to demonstrate failure i am getting in my current project.

It tanspiles and runs, just fails to compile with jest with following error

Error: **error TS1343: The 'import.meta' meta-property is only allowed when the '--module' option is 'es2020', 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node16', or 'nodenext'.**

Files:
src/calc.ts

```
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import path from 'path';
const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

export function add(x: number, y: number): number {
  return x + y;
}

export function mul(x: number, y: number): number {
  return x * y;
}
```

jest.config.cjs:

```
 module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
};
```

tsconfig.json:

```
    {
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "outDir": "./out",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

package.json

```
     "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.6",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  }
```

Not sure if i am doing anything incorrect here

Comment: I have the same case as yours. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I'm wondering the same

Comment: `--module` is not a jest CLI option?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming we're talking about running the tests with test, I found the reason for the error, but I have no idea how to get around it.

Your `"module": "NodeNext"` option is ignored, because `jest` registers `ts-node` with `"module": "CommonJS"`

```js
/// packages/jest-config/src/readConfigFileAndSetRootDir.ts

    // Register TypeScript compiler instance
    const tsNode = await import('ts-node');
    return tsNode.register({
      compilerOptions: {
        module: 'CommonJS',
      },
      moduleTypes: {
        '**': 'cjs',
      },
    });
```

See `jest` [source code](https://github.com/SimenB/jest/blob/v29.6.4/packages/jest-config/src/readConfigFileAndSetRootDir.ts#L117-L119)

This is why the error mentions `nodenext` being a valid choice even though you actually used it in your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: I assume there is a cli option to ovverride ts-config registration not sure on it though..

Comment: Not sure about that. What I eventually did was switch to swc as the transpiler for jest (kept tsc for the rest of the project, for now). Worked out of the box

Answer (score 0):

I decided to switch to bun personally

Comment: and this problem didn't occur when you switched?

Comment: Sorry my answer wasn't clear. Yes it fixed the issue since the test could run perfectly without any useless headache

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer that solves the above problem, but instead of jest runner i used Node inbuilt test runner LTS 20 onward (not everyone will have this luxury) which closed this for me, its a cleaner way to run tests and using tsc to transpile code and test both.